# Tomcat7 dying, nothing in the logs

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7, ubuntu-11.10

I have searched and searched and did not help me much hence posting the new question.
Platform
Ubuntu 11.10 server 64 bit
JVM 1.7.0_03
Tomcat 7

There is nothing special in the configuration - front end server is apache using ajp connector. Tomcat runs as ubuntu service.

On our server, tomcat7 is dying and could not figure out the reason. I have checked all the log files (syslog, catalina.out, even auth.log) to see if there is something getting logged.

As per top command server still has around 4gb of memory free and cpu usage is averaging around 35% most of the times.

In order to isolate the problem, is there any way to get the exit status code of tomcat process that terminated?

I read some reports where jvm logging error log in case of jvm crash. I am not seeing it either.

It seems like I need to set ulimit to get the core dump, but not sure how to do it for tomcat service or is the setting valid for all the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like I need to set ulimit to get the core dump, but not sure how to do it for tomcat service or is the setting valid for all the users.

One way to do that without interfering with anything else would be to add a `ulimit` command to the `catalina.sh` script.  (It is a bit hacky ... but it sounds like you are at the point where hackiness might give happiness.)